Finding $\liminf n (\sin n)^2$
I'm solving an exercise from The elements of Real Analysis by Robert G. Bartle, which asks to find the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the sequence given by $a_n = n (\sin n)^2$.
I have already calculated $\limsup a_n$ as follows: Since $\left\lbrace\sin n : n\in\mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$ is dense in $[-1, 1]$, and $\sin n \neq 1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there are infinite many numbers $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sin m \geq \frac{9}{10}$, and therefore, $m(\sin m)^2\geq \frac{81}{100}m$ for infinite many natural numbers. This implies $a_n$ is not bounded above, so $\limsup a_n = +\infty$.
I was trying to apply something similar to find $\liminf a_n$, but haven't been able to get any conclusion. Can you help me with that, please?

Are you familiar with results on rational approximations like Hurwitz's theorem, Roth's theorem, Liouville's theorem, etc.?

Not really, at this point the book hasn't covered so many advanced concepts like those.

It is $0$ because $\pi$ is irrational and it means that there are integers $p,q$ such that $|\pi - p/q| < 1/q^2$. The last inequality can be proved using "pigeon hole principle".

Do you mind explaining how to proceed, please? I think we can get $\left\lvert \sin(q\pi)-\sin(p)\right\rvert<\left\lvert q\pi-p\right\rvert < 1/q$, so $p(\sin p)^2<p/{q^2}$. Am I on the right track?

For small $x$  sine is of the order $x$. Also you messed up $p$ and $q$ I think. We know that $|q\pi -p|$ is small  and that $sin {q\pi} = 0$. This should do it.

Okay, got it, thank you!

It may not be quite as simple as that: $n(\sin n)^2 \approx 3.226 \times 10^{-7}$ when $n=355$ but I think the next $n$ which gives a lower value may be $n=5419351$.
